# instagram Login in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=ca7816d417c74a5983ead8044548f4f8&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2F10.199.50.80%2FApps%2Fzealcity%2Fwww%2F%23%2Fcallback&response_type=token. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I'm facing this error while enter my instagram username and password in ionic app

My controller coding is:

```
$scope.user = {};
$scope.linkInstagram = function (user) 
{
    $scope.IGUsername = user.Instagramusername;
    $scope.IGPassword = user.Instagrampassword;

    // Communicate with InstaGram API
    $http.get("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/", { params: { "client_id": "ca7816d417c74a5983ead8044548f4f8", "redirect_uri": "http://10.199.50.80/Apps/zealcity/www/#/callback", "response_type": "token" } })
    .success(function (data) 
    {
        $scope.code = data.code;
        $scope.error_type = data.error_type;
        $scope.error_message = data.error_message;
        console.log($scope.error_message);
    })
    .error(function (data) 
    {
        alert("ERROR");
    });
}
```

---

Html page in ionic:

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" hide-nav-bar="true"><form name="form_user" novalidate ng-submit="linkInstagram(user);">
<ion-content class="padding" scroll="false">
  <div class="list" align="center">
    <img src="img/IG_front_photo.jpg" alt="" style="height:320px; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; vertical-align:middle">
  </div>
</ion-content>
<div class="fixed-outside">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Instagram Username" ng-model="user.Instagramusername">
          </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.Instagrampassword">
          </label>
      <button class="button button-positive button-block">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="text-center"><a href="#/app/forgot-password">Forgot password?</a></p>
</div></form></ion-view>
```

Comment: You need to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to your request, the header set as `*`, this will allow requests to be cross domain.

Comment: <access origin="*"/> still not working

Comment: Apologies, I didn't mean to say add the header to the request, it needs to be set server side. You can read more here http://enable-cors.org/ (Find the version that applies to your setup)

Comment: server side means in which one I'm new to ionic.